# Не устанавливается wordpress

Tags: wordpress, openserver, wamp

Столкнулся с проблемой что вп не устанавливается. Не понимаю в чем проблема. Работаю на опен сервере.

После того как я распакую папку и начну устанавливать то всё зависает на этом экране

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точнее не виснет в начинается бесконечная загрузка

Совет подождать неуместен тк я на ночь оставил загружаться и под утро картина осталось той же.

Буквально неделю устанавливал ту же версию вп на том же опен сервере и всё работало + могу взаимодействовать с уже ранее установленными проектами на вп.

В чем может быть причина?

Вот список вещей которые я сделал:
- переустановил вп
- скачал его более раннюю версию вп
- переустановил опен сервер
- попробовал вместо него юзать вамп

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В логах openserver что нибудь есть?

Comment: причина в виндоподелках. И это не последняя проблема. Используй нормальный хостинг. Или хотя бы LAMP в виртуалке